# how to use inArray() to find string in array element if string is surrounded by other characters

Tags: jquery, arrays

How would I search an array using `inArray()` for a value and return `true` even if that value is surrounded by other characters. Here is the code I have (`med` is my array, it goes `med[1-10]`):

```
alprazolamlog = $.inArray('alprazolam', med) > -1;
xanaxlog = $.inArray('xanax', med) > -1;
if (alprazolamlog==true) {
    $("#xanax").css("display", "block");
} else if (xanaxlog==true) {
    $("#xanax").css("display", "block");
}
```

It returns `true` if the array element is "xanax" or "alprazolam". But if a user enters "xanax xr" or "alprazolam er" it will return `false`. Is there any way to search for string "xanax" or "alprazolam" at any point in that particular array element, even if there are other characters in that particular array element, and to return `true` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$.inArray()` if you're looking for a partial match.  It just doesn't work that way.  Instead, you can just iterate the array yourself and do whatever kind of match against each element of the array that you want.

There's no magic to `$.inArray()`.  It's just a shortcut for finding an exact value in an array, but if that shortcut isn't exactly what you want, then just do your own iteration and your own type of comparison.

For example:

```
function findPartialStrInArray(array, target) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var item = array[i];
        // if this array element is a string and contains the target string
        if (typeof item === "string" && item.indexOf(target) !== -1) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var alprazolamlog = findPartialStrInArray(med, 'alprazolam') > -1;
var xanaxlog = findPartialStrInArray(med, 'xanax') > -1;
```

Comment: By iterate do you mean something like using a for loop and doing a comparison through each element?

Comment: @user3898186 - To iterate over an array, you can either use a `for` loop or the `.forEach()` method on the array.  See the example I added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Looks great, I will give it a shot after work today

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var search_pattern = /llo/;
var data = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello world', 'im in an array'];    
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    if(item.match(search_pattern))
        console.log(item) 
});
```

you could also just break the foreach after getting one positiv result or return the position in array with `return i;`