# How to get specific element within an array without knowing the exact string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

TLDR;
**Is there any way to use `$.inArray` by only knowing what the element begins with or contains?**

I have an array of elements and I would like to be able to pick out an element that begins with a certain string as the value is dynamic.

For example:

My array is:

```
array = ["Alpha_GB8732", "Beta_GB29834", "Gamma_GB2384", "Delta_GB23984"]
```

But for each user, the order and the exact names may change.

Use jQuery, I can do the following to get the element if I know the exact value.

```
var order = $.inArray("Alpha_GB8732", array)
$item = $(array).get(order)
```

However, since everything after GB changes for each element on the page load, I cannot use this as I do not know the exact string.

Is there any way to use `$.inArray` by only knowing what the element begins with or contains?

## ANSWER

Thanks so much for all of your help guys! I really appreciate it.

In the end, the best answer for me was Louis's response:

```
let array = ["Alpha_GB8732", "Beta_GB29834", "Gamma_GB2384", "Delta_GB23984"]
let result = array.filter((el) => el.includes("Alpha_GB") === true);
console.log(result);
```

This didn't work for me at first... because `gulp-uglify` for some reason couldn't compile the *es6* script. So, just for anyone out there who may have the same problem when compiling, here is the same thing but in *es5*:

```
array = ["Alpha_GB8732", "Beta_GB29834", "Gamma_GB2384", "Delta_GB23984"]
var result = array.filter(function (el) {
    return el.includes("Alpha_GB") === true;
});
console.log(result);
```

Again, thanks a lot for your help everyone! (@Louis, @ControlAltDel)

Comment: you could use array.filter

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25073710/how-to-use-inarray-to-find-string-in-array-element-if-string-is-surrounded-by

Comment: You can use indexOf and if it return > -1, it is present. If you have the beginning, you can use [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/startsWith)

Comment: also for RegEx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447021/can-i-use-a-regular-expression-within-jquery-inarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on ControlAltDel's comment, you can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). See the example below;

```js
let array = ["Alpha_GB8732", "Beta_GB29834", "Gamma_GB2384", "Delta_GB23984"]
let result = array.filter((el) => el.includes("Alpha_GB") === true);
console.log(result);

// You could turn this in to a function
function arrayContains(arr, str){
  return arr.filter((el) => el.includes("Alpha_GB") === true).length > 0;
}

console.log(arrayContains(array, 'Alpha_GB')); // returns true

// And use it like this
//if(arrayContains(array, 'Alpha_GB')){}...
```

Comment: This is a great solution as I really needed it to only include the string as opposed to being an exact match. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter, like

```
array = ["Alpha_GB8732", "Beta_GB29834", "Gamma_GB2384", "Delta_GB23984"]
var find = array.filter(function(item) {
  return (this === "Alpha_GB8732");
});
find = (find.length > 0) ? find[0] : null;
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you'd post an answer too =) Mine's based on your comment. FWIW, this is a better implementation anyway.

Comment: Actually, won't yours only return true if there's an exact full-string match?

Comment: @Lewis yes. But nothing is stopping you from using a regex in place of string equals.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to filter out the array based upon some characters inside it This is how it should work:

```
const MyArray = ["Alpha_GB8732", "Beta_GB29834", "Gamma_GB2384", "Delta_GB23984"]

//you can replace .startswith() with any function that you might need. you can also apply .toLowerCase() to filter case-insensitive items

const filteredArray = MyArray.filter((x) => x.startsWith("N"));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Hope it helps!